# How to convert date (not datetime) to epoch format while running sql query?

Tags: sql, database

So, my table has a date field named `batch` that looks like this when I do
`select batch from my_table;`

[image]

However, i want this to be converted to the epoch representation, so that all rows contain the epoch value when I select. I tried the following query but it didn't work:

`select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(batch) FROM my_table;`

So, do i need to convert to datetime first? How do I get this to work?

Comment: Does your query not work?

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` certainly works on dates.  What is the problem?

Comment: are you sure you are using mysql ?

Comment: My apoligies, it's for sql, and not mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does work

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01')
-- returns 1577833200

select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01 00:00:00')
-- returns 1577833200
```